# jQuery Change Tooltip data-cache-title

Tags: jquery

I am using tooltip on an element to display the title the way i want it.

```
<span id="backup_marker" class="fa-lock" title="Original Title" data-uk-tooltip=""></span>
```

If i hover the element before the click the output in firebug is the following.

```
<span id="backup_marker" class="fa-lock" title="" data-uk-tooltip="" data-cached-title="Original Title"></span>
```

The following code will change the title but won't update the data-cache-title if i have hovered the element before i trigger the click so it still displays the "Original Title".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#download_backup').click(function() {
        $('#backup_marker').prop('title', 'New Title');
        //or
        $('#backup_marker').attr('title', 'New Title');
    });
});
```

Is there a way to change the displayable tooltip title after its been cached in data-cache-title?

**Update:**
I have tried the following with no luck

```
$('#backup_marker').attr('data-cached-title', 'New Title');
$('#backup_marker').data('cached-title', 'New Title');
$('#backup_marker').data('cached-title') === 'New Title';
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5 ?

Comment: are you using a 3rd party js library for tooltips? if so, which one?

Comment: Tooltip is: https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/tooltip.html

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery().attr method should work:

```
$('#backup_marker').attr('data-cached-title', 'new value')
```

or the data() method

```
$('#backup_marker').data('cached-title', 'new value')
```

Comment: I had no luck with both of them.